# Is it possible to prioritize Typescript class custom static fields in VSCode's intellisense

Tags: typescript, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense

If you create a class in Typescript using VSCode and you add a static method to it, the intellisense on the class itself is showing the fields and methods of that class (even the once created by the language itself) but sorts them alphabetically.

I was wondering if it was possible to show custom static fields and methods first since they are probably what you are going to call anyway.

[image: example]

In the example above, the method `someMethod` is last in the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a few months old and I can't duplicate this with identical code on the latest version of VSCode:

[image: suggestion issue]

If you're still encountering this I'd make sure you haven't modified the IntelliSense settings. The other option is to use `"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,` which controls whether sorting favors words that appear close to the cursor.

These are my Intellisense TS settings:

[image]

Comment: I was able to reproduce by using my workspace's typescript version (typescript v.3.8.3) so maybe that what is causing the issue ? Locality bonus is interesting but not really what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't see why the TS version would matter in this situation though since the Intellisense used by VSCode for TS is provided directly by VSCode so it should have the changes if you are on the latest VSCode release. Can you spin a new directory with NPM, install the latest version of typescript there, and see if it still happens? Other than that the only thing I can think is some setting within the Intellisense settings is incorrectly set for Typescript. I updated my answer wit ha screenshot of my Intellisense TS settings.